# Find function argument spec for introspected methods

Tags: python, introspection, pygobject

I'm developing an app using PyGI - Python 2.7 and GTK+ 3 through GObject introspection.

How do I find a function's arguments and argument types of functions that are invoked using introspection?

Specifically, `Gio.File.replace_contents_async()`.  I found that the C definition does not match the one in PyGI ([gio C docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-replace-contents-async)).  I've tried using the interactive shell and using help(Gio.File.replace_conents_async) and inspect.getargspec(...), but they just state that it takes vargs.  Right now, I keep putting dummy arguments to see what warning or exceptions are printed to see what arguments it needs.

Gtk documentation isn't complete, but I've found enough to solve some problems related to it.
I started this app using Ubuntu's 'quickly' tool and didn't expect development to be so difficult with PyGI... lack of documentation, no source to look at...

Comment: For some of these poorly-documented wrappers, best bet is to examine the wrapper source code.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of PyGI (>= 3.10) have doc strings which contain argument names and types:

```
>>> from gi.repository import Gio
>>> Gio.File.replace_contents_async.__doc__
'replace_contents_async(self, contents:list, etag:str=None, make_backup:bool,
flags:Gio.FileCreateFlags, cancellable:Gio.Cancellable=None,
callback:Gio.AsyncReadyCallback=None, user_data=None)'
```

Using help(Gio.File.replace_conents_async) doesn't seem to show this.

There is also some very nice Python specific documentation for repositories available here:
http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/interfaces/File.html#Gio.File.replace_contents_async